# Deleting item from database

Tags: database, vb.net

```
Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
    If lstDetails.SelectedItems.Count = 1 Then
        Dim Button = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this Data?", _
        "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)

        If Button = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
            Dim dt As New LoginSystemDataSet.AdministratorDataTable
            dt = AdministratorTableAdapter.DeleteQuery(lstDetails.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(0).ToString, lstDetails.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(0).ToString, lstDetails.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(0).ToString)
            lstDetails.Items.Remove(lstDetails.SelectedItems.Item(0))
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox("No items is selected", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End If

End Sub
```

How do I delete a record from the database when the button is clicked.

Comment: Do you have any sql? And code to call the DB?

Comment: Me.AdministratorTableAdapter.Fill(Me.LoginSystemDataSet.Administrator)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `AdminitratorTableAdapter` class is already set to do the `DELETE` operation. You should step through the code and debug it.

If you want to do a regular `DELETE`, you do something like the following. After replacing the stuff in CAPS with the values relevant to your situation. Also `ID` field is just an example. You should replace it with whatever fieldname the `lstDetails`'s selected Items stands for.

```
Dim dbCommand As SqlCommand
Dim strSQL As String

Using dbConnection as New SqlConnection("Data Source=YOUR_SQL_SERVER_NAME;Initial Catalog=YOUR_DB_NAME;Integrated Security=True")
    Try
        dbConnection.Open()
        strSQL = "DELETE FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME WHERE ID = @ID"
        dbCommand = New SqlCommand(strSQL, dbConnection)
        dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", lstDetails.SelectedItems.Item(0))
        dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        dbConnection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' handle Exception, log it etc.
    End Try
End Using
```

Comment: You forgot `dbConnection.Dispose()`. Or you could have used a `Using` structure to handle that for you.

Comment: Wasn't sure `Using` was available in `VB.Net`. Thanks, I updated the code.